# Does Django bulk_create lock the entire table while inserting the rows?

Tags: django, postgresql, bulkinsert

I'm using Django 1.6 and postgres, would a bulk_create on a specific table lock the entire table? (in my case I'm bulk creating 10,000 rows and it takes ~10 seconds) I've tested this while creating objects every half second while the bulk create was happening and none of those individual creates hung but I'd just like to make sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bulk_create` inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are), so it blocks the table to perform **atomic transaction**.

usage: `bulk_create(obj_list, batch_size=None)`

The `batch_size` parameter controls how many objects are created in single query. The default is to create all objects in one batch, except for SQLite where the default is such that at most 999 variables per query are used.

The following [article](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/) can also give you an idea how fast is **bulk_create** relativly to other methods.